# Navigation from within a HOC in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, higher-order-functions

I wish to add a check to every page in my app. The check is that if a file exists then pull the user to a page.

I think that a HOC is one way to do this (are there others?)

and I have come up with this

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationScreenProp } from "react-navigation";
import RNFS from "react-native-fs";

interface MyComponentProps {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
}

interface MyComponentState {}

const importFileCheck = WrappedComponent => {
  class HOC extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
        RNFS.exists(
         ".\path\I\care\about.xml"
        ).then(exists => {
          if (exists) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Export");               
          }
        });
      });
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return HOC;
};

export default importFileCheck;
```

When I run the page I get an error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.addListener)

So I guess that the navigation 'thing' is not being passed through properly

For completion I use the HOC like so

```
importFileCheck(App)
```

and `App` has the navigation stuff already in it, and works without the HOC.

Imports are

> "react": "16.6.1",
>   "react-native": "0.57.7",
>    "react-navigation": "3.2.0"

**Further details for the keen :D**

First I make a stack navigator that is all the pages in my app

```
const appNav = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Calculator: {
            screen: Calculator,
            navigationOptions: { title: "Calculator" }
        },
   // more pages
);

export default createAppContainer(appNav);
```

In `App.tsx`

this gets 'wrapped' in other components

```
const WrappedStack = () => {
  return <RootStack screenProps={{ t: i18n.getFixedT() }} />;
};

const ReloadAppOnLanguageChange = translate("translation", {
  bindI18n: "languageChanged",
  bindStore: false
})(WrappedStack);

 class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>
          <Provider
            ManureStore={ManureStore}
            SettingsStore={SettingsStore}
            FieldStore={FieldStore}
            CalculatorStore={CalculatorStore}
            FarmStore={FarmStore}
          >
            <ReloadAppOnLanguageChange />
          </Provider>
        </StyleProvider>
      </I18nextProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

and finally we wrap with my new HOC

```
export default importFileCheck(App)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this defeated me (and the navigation event I wanted to use does not fire when an app returns from the background anyway)

this is my solution

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavigationScreenProp } from "react-navigation";
import RNFS from "react-native-fs";
import { AppState } from "react-native";

interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
}

interface State {}

export default class ImportFileCheck extends Component<Props, State> {
  private _handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    if (nextAppState === "active") {
      RNFS.exists(
        RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/Inbox/Import.json"
      ).then(exists => {
        if (exists) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Export");
        }
      });
    }
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  public componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }
  public render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then within each page files `return` statement I slap in a `<ImportFileCheck navigation={navigation} />`

What a hack!

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to see what the error is when you have not provided any examples of how the component is used within `react-navigation`. Since the issue is related to the navigation prop not being passed it would be helpful to see a more complete example of how the HOC is used within the application, with all the `react-navigation` details.

That said, maybe you could try using the `withNavigation` HOC to ensure that the navigation prop is present. It is documented here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that... also I have added a bunch of code to try and give context, or you can see the whole damn lot here (without the hoc as that is not committed yet... due to this issue :D ) https://github.com/fo-am/iCrapAppPro (look in src dir)

Comment: I altered my HOC like so `return withNavigation(HOC);` and I get the error `Invariant Violation: withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator. The wrapped component is unable to get access to navigation from props or context` which suggests the same problem of me not passing `navigation` around in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `useNavigation` hooks of `react-navigation` with version 5.x.x or later.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

then initialize the `navigation` using `useNavigation` like

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

and then use `navigation` for different navigation actions like.

```
navigation.navigate('ToScreen');
naviagtion.goBack();
```

Hope this will help someone.